# change element on one page only

Tags: html, css

On this site https://www.nycofficesuites.com/new/, I want to change the color of the top bar on the homepage only.  I have tried this code:

```
.home .page .page-id-94 .page-template .page-template-template-home .page-template-template-home-php .wood .top-bar {
  background:blue;
}
```

as well as this code:

```
.page-id-94 .top-bar {
  background:blue;
}
```

Neither work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's not how you should ask a good question. Please read: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show some of your `HTML` mark up and we can help you

Comment: This sounds like a job for jQuery!

Comment: The page is built on the WordPress framework.  You can access the admin, select Pages, and change the background color on the file.

Comment: @the_pete – No, no it definitely does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your website, and there're a huge hoard of classnames on one `body` element.

Problem: There're spaces in all your selectors.

`.class1 .class2` selects an element with a classname of `class2` that's the child of an element with the classname `class1`.

`.class1.class2` has no spaces in the selector, so it selects one element with both classnames of `.class1` and `.class2`.

Correction:

```
.home.page.page-id-94.page-template.page-template-template-home.page-template-template-home-php.wood .top-bar {
    background:blue;
}
```

OR:

```
.page-id-94 .top-bar {
    background:blue;
}
```

There's a space before the last selector because `.top-bar` is a child of the `body` element.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
.home header.style-4 .top-bar {
  background: #YOURCOLOUR;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's a single page you could just set the style with !important

```
<div style="background:red!important;">
    <p>Example</p>
</div>
```